# How to remove a file from firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase hosting with firebase functions which will serve the homepage based on the type of device being served.

Earlier my homepage was served through `index.html` file. But now I dont want a index.html to be served when my domain is hit. I have configured homepage to be served throught functions `/` route. Its working well in my local.

But when i deploy it, the old `index.html` is still being served.

How can i remove this file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order), Firebase Hosting will always prefer to serve static content over any rewrites for functions:

> Priority order of Hosting responses
>
> The different Firebase Hosting configuration options described on this
> page can sometimes overlap. If there is a conflict, Hosting determines
> its response using the following priority order:
>
> 1. Reserved namespaces that begin with a /__/* path segment
> 2. Configured redirects
> 3. Exact-match static content
> 4. Configured rewrites
> 5. Custom 404 page
> 6. Default 404 page

See that static content comes before rewrites.

It sounds like you still have an index.html file in your static content for deployment.  You should just remove that file from your local project, and deploy again to remove it from Firebase, so that the path is served by a function rewrite instead.